# How to make Jenkins 2.0 works with GitLab 8.7

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, integration, gitlab, jenkins-2

I'm not sure if it's right place to ask this question, but I read a lot on the Internet and I tried a lot making GitLab 8.7 (actually, I'm talking about http://gitlab.com) and my own private Jenkins instance work together.

I followed the https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin and http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html documentations, but:

1. Testing the connection between the **Jenkins CI Service** of GitLab and the **GitLab Plugin** of Jenkins is causing an `NullPointerException` (because an `X-GitLab-Event` header is missing when GitLab fetch Jenkins)
2. The Jenkins build is properly triggered  using a **Webhook** instead of the **Jenkins CI Service** (but this method seems deprecated according to GitLab's docs)
3. I can't figure out to make GitLab retreive Jenkins build status (mainly because I do not have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` in my GIT repo... But I do not need one because I want to use Jenkins)
4. ...What about the GitLab's **Runners**?

Do you guys manage to make it works?

Thanks a lot,

Radium.

Comment: The latter documentation applies to the enterprise edition of GitLab, are you using that or the community edition?

Comment: It's about the EE and https://gitlab.com and I'm using the last one :)